# Images from events

Tags: 7, media

I have two content types I want to link (join contents). Action and "images from action". What is a typical way in Drupal to create an album relating to certain action from the past and link to it?
So far I'm thinking about `insert module`. Is it on good way? I'm using Drupal 7.

I found [this](http://www.malagronda.it/en/photos-country-house-umbria) site that shows what I'd like to set in Drupal. I can see `Photographs` section in the menu and it's three submenus `Apartments, Outsie, Swimming pool`.
What modules do I need to have this similar? I guess it's using `insert` module and `colorbox`. Are there some other modules involved?

In the menu (section Photos) I'd like to have something like
2011
- January
- February
-- Photos from action 1 (February 1)
-- Photos from action 2 (February 4)
- March
...
2012
- January
- February
...

I'd like to have these tree generated automatically from events. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "join contents"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno e.g. (Event X from 06/01/2011, Images relating to event X from 06/01/2011)